# If A and B then C?

Tags: logic

I'm working on a mathematical proof, but the problem I'm having is more to do with logic than math per se.

I'm wondering if these two are equivalent:

If A and B then C

If A and not B, then not C.

Comment: If and only if "B then C", right?

Comment: It's just a one way implication, if that clarifies something.

Comment: NO, check it with truth table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since they have different truth conditions: `(A∧B)→C` is false only when `A=T,B=T,C=F`, while `(A∧~B)→~C` is true in that case. You can verify this using [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).